# Не получается отправить запись в БД MySQL через HTML-форму

Tags: php, mysql

```
//Выдает такие ошибки:
    //https://wampi.ru/image/6IZ9c2J
    <?php

    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'thismovie');

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        prinf("Соеденение не установлено", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');

    $query = "INSERT INTO music1 VALUES(null, '$name', '$author'))"; 

    while ( $row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
        echo $row['name'].$row['author']."<br>";
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO music1 values(null, 'name', 'author',))";
    $mysqli->query($query);

    $mysqli->close();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Домашка</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="player.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="название композиции"><br>
    <input type="text" name="author" placeholder="исполнитель"><br>    
    <input type="submit" value="добавить">
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Сначала нужно создать переменные: $name = $_POST['name'], а потом уже работать с ними

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'thismovie');

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        prinf("Соеденение не установлено", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');

$name = $_POST['name'];
$author = $_POST['author'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO music1 VALUES(null, '$name', '$author'))"; 

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['name'].$row['author'];
$mysqli->close();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Домашка</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="player.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="название композиции"><br>
    <input type="text" name="author" placeholder="исполнитель"><br>    
    <input type="submit" value="добавить">
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```